# Is there any function such that $x^\prime(t) = x(t)^t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This seems like a simple ODE, yet I can't find any solution to it. It can be solved numerically, but I would be interested in an analytic solution, or proof that none exists. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well solution does exists... But i believe you ask for more than that

Comment: @Typhon, thanks for the reply. I know that $x(t) = 0$ is a solution; I was looking for a less trivial one, however. Perhaps I should word my questions better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Similar to [Possible to solve this differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100140):

$x'(t)=x(t)^t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=(e^{\ln x})^t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=e^{t\ln x}$

Let $u=\ln x$ ,

Then $x=e^u$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=e^u\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore e^u\dfrac{du}{dt}=e^{tu}$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=e^{(t-1)u}$

Let $v=t-1$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{du}{dv}\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{du}{dv}$

$\therefore\dfrac{du}{dv}=e^{vu}$

Let $w=vu$ ,

Then $u=\dfrac{w}{v}$

$\dfrac{du}{dv}=\dfrac{1}{v}\dfrac{dw}{dv}-\dfrac{w}{v^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{v}\dfrac{dw}{dv}-\dfrac{w}{v^2}=e^w$

$\dfrac{1}{v}\dfrac{dw}{dv}=e^w+\dfrac{w}{v^2}$

$(e^wv^2+w)\dfrac{dv}{dw}=v$

Let $z=v^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dz}{dw}=2v\dfrac{dv}{dw}$

$\therefore\dfrac{e^wv^2+w}{2v}\dfrac{dz}{dw}=v$

$(v^2+we^{-w})\dfrac{dz}{dw}=2e^{-w}v^2$

$(z+we^{-w})\dfrac{dz}{dw}=2e^{-w}z$

Let $s=z+we^{-w}$ ,

Then $z=s-we^{-w}$

$\dfrac{dz}{dw}=\dfrac{ds}{dw}+(w-1)e^{-w}$

$\therefore s\dfrac{ds}{dw}+(w-1)e^{-w}s=2e^{-w}(s-we^{-w})$

$s\dfrac{ds}{dw}=(3-w)e^{-w}s-2we^{-2w}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.